# In Rummikub, does a joker count towards the 30 points contract?

Tags: scoring, rummikub, joker

If you have a joker in your initial hand of 14 tiles, can it be played in a meld adding its value in order to pass the 30 points contract?

I.e. does a joker have the value of the number it replaces?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is almost literally in [the rules](https://tesera.ru/images/items/784463/Rummikub_Rules.pdf):

> The Joker:
>
> There are two jokers in the game. They can be used for any
> tile in a set. **A joker used in the opening set scores the value of the
> tiles it represents.** A joker can be retrieved from a set on the table
> by a player who can replace it during his turn with a tile of the same
> numerical value and color it represents. The tile used to replace the
> Joker must come from a player's rack and not from the table. In the
> case of a group of 3, the joker can be replaced by the tile of either
> of the missing colors. A joker that has been replaced must be used in
> the player's same turn with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a
> new set. Players cannot retrieve a joker before they have laid their
> initial set(s). A set containing a joker can have tiles added to it
> and can be split apart or  have tiles removed from it. The joker has a
> penalty value of 30 points if it remains on a player's rack at the end
> of a game.

Comment: TIL that we've severely house-ruled Rummikub.